# Need help to prove an identity about arithmetic and geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

Suppose $a=a_5,b=a_{17},c=a_{37}$ of an arithmetic sequence are also geometric sequence  .

How can prove $$a^{b-c}\times b^{c-a}\times c^{a-b}=1$$ ?
I tried to find geometric common ratio, that is $q=\frac{37-17}{17-5}=\frac{20}{12}=\frac{5}{3}$ and plug into formula ...but I am lost in calculations. I tried also to write $$a,b,c\\\frac{k}{q},k,kq$$ but I get stuck on this . 
  I  do appreciate your help ?(or any other idea)

Comment: Is this the complete question? I am also getting the same result as @lab got, that is $d=0$. Also, how are you getting the common ratio as $\frac{5}{3}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using condition of geometric progression we have:
 $ac=b^2$, so that $$\log(a)+\log(c) = 2\log(b)$$

Then lets assume:

$$a^{b-c}\times b^{c-a}\times c^{a-b}=k\\
(b-c)\log(a) + (c-a) \log(b) +(a-b)\log(c) = \log(k)$$

Let the arithmetic progression have common difference $d$ between its terms. Then we can say 
$$a-b=-12d;\
b-c = -20;\
c-a = 32d$$

Using this, our equation becomes:

$$-20d\log(a) +32d \log(b) -12d\log(c) = \log(k)\\
8d \log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) = \log(k)$$

If $k$ has to be $1$, we **must** have $d=0$, or identically $\frac{b}{a} = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

We have $\dfrac ba=\dfrac cb=k$(say) $\implies a=bk,c=ak^2$

$$\left(\dfrac cb\right)^a\left(\dfrac ac\right)^b\left(\dfrac ba\right)^c=\dfrac{k^ak^c}{(k^2)^b}=k^{a+c-2b}$$

So, we need $a+c-2b=0\iff a,b,c$ in arithmetic progression as well.

Comment: with respect to $a+c-2b=0$ if I put $$(a_1+4d)+(a_1+36d)-2(a_1+16d)=0 \to \\40d-32d=0  \\ \implies d=0  $$  ??

Comment: Surely $\dfrac ba=\dfrac cb=k$(say) $\implies a=\frac bk,c=ak^2$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We have $\dfrac ba=\dfrac cb=k$(say) $\implies a=bk,c=ak^2$

Replace the values of $b,c$ in the base

As $b=A+(17-1)D,a=a+(5-1)D$ etc. where $A,D$ are the first term & the common difference respectively.

$b-a=?$

The values of $b-c$ etc. in the exponent.

Comment: Observe that $$17-5+(37-17)+(5-37)=0$$